# what is "copy to pixmap" feature on compiz?

Tags: compiz

I want to reduce my compiz effects because of my limited graphics card.
Is it safe to disable "copy to pixmap" feature on my compiz?

(I'm using 14.04 Trusty Tahr Daily Build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. However, nobody knows what is the setting for. It is reported that it can improve smoothiness in window movement. Try with this option and without. It shouldn't crash.

It is probably an opengl feature – its a way for drawing stuff without getting visual artifacts on the screen. There are better ways to speed compiz and unity up like disabling the animation.

When you turn it off and on you can see that Unity reloads icons which is not surprising – the window manager probably need to refresh everything when you toggled that option.

Comment: thank you. I've tried it, and my ubuntu still fine.
But still I want to know what it's for

Comment: see the update in the answer

Comment: @rofiquzzaki: If my answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.